# SQL Date grouping

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2005, group-by

I want to ask about SQL Server 2005 about date grouping with other sum field.

```
| tanggal             | nama                    | qty  |
|---------------------|-------------------------|------|
| 2017-07-11 06:25:00 | APEL                    | 4.00 |
| 2017-07-11 06:25:00 | SUSU KENTAL MANIS PUTIH | 4.00 |
| 2017-07-11 06:29:00 | APEL                    | 4.00 |
| 2017-07-11 06:29:00 | SUSU KENTAL MANIS PUTIH | 4.00 |
| 2017-07-10 06:29:00 | APEL                    | 2.00 |
| 2017-07-10 06:29:00 | SUSU KENTAL MANIS PUTIH | 2.00 |
| 2017-07-11 00:00:00 | APEL                    | 1.00 |
| 2017-07-11 00:00:00 | SUSU KENTAL MANIS PUTIH | 1.00 |
```

and I need result like this

```
| Tanggal    | Barang                  | Jumlah |
|------------|-------------------------|--------|
| 2017-07-10 | APEL                    | 2.00   |
| 2017-07-10 | SUSU KENTAL MANIS PUTIH | 2.00   |
| 2017-07-11 | APEL                    | 9.00   |
| 2017-07-11 | SUSU KENTAL MANIS PUTIH | 9.00   |
```

Here's the code

```
select j.tanggal [Tanggal],p.nama [Barang],sum(p.qty) [Jumlah] 
from proses p
left join jual j on j.kode=p.kode 
group by j.tanggal,p.kodeItem,p.nama,p.unit,p.kode
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select j.tanggal [Tanggal],p.nama [Barang],sum(p.qty) [Jumlah] 

from proses p
left join jual j on j.kode=p.kode 

order by date
```

If this does not work, you may try using union instead of join.

Answer (score 0):

use `CAST` to change the first column from a datetime to a date, there were some unnecessary columns in group by which I have removed too:

```
select 
cast(j.tanggal as date) [Tanggal],
p.nama [Barang],
sum(p.qty) [Jumlah] 
from proses p
left join jual j on j.kode=p.kode 
group by cast(j.tanggal as date),p.nama
```

Comment: It still not work to group date, but thanks for answer.

j.tanggal as smalldatetime